# Failing to setup two distinct packages in the same project with NetBeans IDE 19

Tags: java, exception, command, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to setup a project in NetBeans IDE 19 to have two packages in order to test Java protected access modifier.

My setup is the following:

```
Project: TestAccessModifiersProtected
   \- package: com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotecteda
       |- class: TestAccessModifiersProtectedA.java
   \- package: com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotectedb
       |- class: TestAccessModifiersProtectedB.java
```

when trying to run the code in `TestAccessModifiersProtectedB.java` class I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotected.TestAccessModifiersProtected
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotected.TestAccessModifiersProtected
Command execution failed
```

I have tried:

- changing the package `com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotecteda` to `com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotected` and run `TestAccessModifiersProtectedB.java` - result: same error
- changing also the package `com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotectedb` to `com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotected` and run `TestAccessModifiersProtectedB.java` - result: same error
- change classes to `TestAccessModifiersProtected`

---

My code is the following:

##### TestAccessModifiersProtectedA.java

```
package com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotecteda;

public class TestAccessModifiersProtectedA {
    
    protected void display() {
        System.out.println("TestAccessModifiersProtectedA");
    }
}
```

##### TestAccessModifiersProtectedB.java

```
package com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotectedb;
import com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotecteda.*;

class TestAccessModifiersPotectedB extends TestAccessModifiersProtectedA {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestAccessModifiersPotectedB obj = new TestAccessModifiersPotectedB();
        
        /* Prints "TestAccessModifiersPotectedA" */
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

---

Any ideas as to why NetBeans fails to run code in `TestAccessModifiersProtectedB.java`? Why is it taking the project name (`TestAccessModifiersProtected`) literal for my packages + classes?

I would expect to build the path to the class by including the package and the class so as to resolve such cases.

How can I succeed in keeping two packages separated in the same project?

Comment: why don't you declare those classes as public? the default is package scope

Comment: @Stultuske , would that matter though? isn't it a matter of project concatenation for determining PATH to class, instead of package?

N.B. I tried setting `TestAccessModifiersPotectedB` to **public** and I get the same error so it seems declaring classes public isn't affecting behavior here

Comment: First step in trying to solve issues: carefully reading the error message:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.agheorghe.testaccessmodifiersprotected.TestAccessModifiersProtected
It's not looking for TestAccessModifiersProtectedB or TestAccessModifiersProtectedA, but for a class called TestAccessModifiersProtected, and I don't see such a class in your code

Comment: @Stultuske , I tried refactoring to `TestAccessModifiersProtected` and it still didn't work. I tried the one I'm trying to run, the other one I'm extending and both. Failed in all cases.

Comment: did you notice the packages are also not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to name both the package and the class in the way the project is named.

For example, for project `TestMyProject`, NetBeans IDE 19 will expect a package: `com.mycompany.testmyproject` and a class `TestMyProject.java` in that package.

Comment: only if your project is configured to expect this. normally, this makes no sense